# br в CSS. Какой код написать?

Tags: html, css

Какой код написать в CSS, чтобы br в HTML-е не написали?

```html
<ul class="menu__f__small">
    <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a            id="header__item__footer">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="catalog__item__footer">Каталог</a></li>
    <br class="menu__item__f__small__br">
    <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="delivery__item__footer">Дотавка и оплата</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="bonuses__form__item__footer">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="reviews__item__footer">О нас</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `white-space: pre-line/pre-wrap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте псевдокласс `:nth-child`. Пример:

```css
li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__f__small">
  <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="header__item__footer">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="catalog__item__footer">Каталог</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="delivery__item__footer">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="bonuses__form__item__footer">Контакты</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item__f__small"><a id="reviews__item__footer">О нас</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилась решить задачу, но через position: absolute.

Comment: замечательный костыль

Comment: может покажите как? мне любопытно

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu__f__small li:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 79px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: ой-ой, не делайте так никогда)